# A template class that produces typename and typedef related errors in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a class Tran that contains an instance of a class Car. If the program includes `typename` before `typedef`, it produces an error: "expected nested-name-specifier before `typedef` ". If it does not include `typename`, it produces an error: "need 'typename' before 'Tran::CarType::Model' because 'Tran::CarType' is a dependent scope". What is causing this problem?

```
#include "Car.hpp"

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Tran {

    public: 
    typedef Car<A, B> CarType;  //compilation error
    typedef CarType::Model M;   //compilation error

private: 
CarType myCar;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
typedef CarType::Model M;
```

Here, note that `CarType` is defined as

```
typedef Car<A, B> CarType;
```

Notice that `CarType` depends on what `A` and `B` are.  In fact, it's called a *dependent type* because of this.

In C++, if you want to access a type nested inside of a dependent type, you have to explicitly tell the compiler that you are looking inside of a dependent type for the name of some other type.  Therefore, this line is an error:

```
typedef CarType::Model M;
```

Because there is no indication that `Model` is a type name.  To fix this, change the line to read

```
typedef typename CarType::Model M;
```

Here, the `typename` keyword indicates to C++ that `Model` is the name of a type nested inside the dependent type `CarType`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should have guessed that this question was yours... *template typedef* :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas- I was thinking that as I typed this up. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The correct order is `typedef typename` and not the other way around. You only need it in the second declaration, as it is a dependent name and the compiler cannot know during the first phase of lookup what `CarType::Model` is.